# Generating circular histogram plot of joint directions from vector layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I would like to extract the joint direction from a vector layer. Joints are best described 'relaxation fractures' found on rock outcrops are are easily visible if no vegetation exists. The orientation of joints can show the local stress directions caused by faulting or other tectonic activity.

I have identified an outcrop with visible joints and marked the dominant joints as a line within a vector layer - see image. Read lines are the joint directions.[image: Limestone outcrop showing vector lines representing]. I can see the information I need in the 'Identify Features' option but cannot extract the X1,y1 and x2,y2 information to calculate azimuths.

Are there any plugins to extract azimuths of lines in a vector shapefile within a specified polygon (I would like to extract information within specified areas rather than creating many different 'joint' shapefiles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 solutions to my query.

Simplest solution is to install the QGIS [Line Direction Histogram plugin](http://arken.umb.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/LineDirectionHistogram/). That plots nicely a polar diagram of the selected features within a layer. However, there is no way to display the information with the shape file or spatially within QGIS.

The second way is more mechanical:
Use MMQGIS plugin to generate a geomtry output as a CSV file (saving node file). If the data is in X and Y values import CSV file into a spreadsheet and perform simple trigonometry to caluclate the 'bearing'. Import data into an open source stereonet software (examples below) and plot a polar diagram of the lineament (http://www.geo.cornell.edu/geology/faculty/RWA/programs.html or http://www.igc.usp.br/index.php?id=openstereo). The trig assumptiuons are OK for short lineament distances (100s metres).

If the output from MMQGIS is in lat and longs then the equation for handling that is explained at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html. The formula for calculating a bearing from two points in Excel is:
=ATAN2(COS(lat1)*SIN(lat2)-SIN(lat1)*COS(lat2)*COS(lon2-lon1),SIN(lon2-lon1)*COS(lat2)) Where Lat1 and Lon1 are the first point and Lat2 and Lon2 is the last point. These values are in Radians.

Comment: Newer versions of the Line Direction Histogram plugin allows the user to provide a polygon layer that is used to "tile" the line dataset.  For each tile, a histogram is produced, and the result is presented as a point layer consisting of one point per tile, with each point styled with the line direction histogram / rose diagram for the tile.  See http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/LineDirectionHistogram for more information (tiles in a regular grid). Direct link to an illustration in that document: http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/LineDirectionHistogram/_images/tiling.png